# Can you use MSI B45 with an RTX 3080?

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

**Motherboard Specification:** https://www.manualslib.com/manual/107276/Msi-G45.html?page=14#manual

It says I have `PCI_E1`, `PCI_E2` and `PCI_E3` slots but I am not sure if these PCIe slots support an RTX 3080 because it says [here](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/107276/Msi-G45.html?page=36#manual) that the `PCIE_E2` slot only processes up to 250mb/s transfer rate.

Comment: What are you planning to use this system for? The motherboard seems to be pretty old and not capable of running a processor that would adequately support that gpu

Answer (score 0):

It will run any gpu with a pcie 16x slot, like the 3080. You probably will get a cpu bottleneck with a 3080. Please search for something cheaper like a 2070. to get less of a cpu bottleneck. (or even a 1060 if you do mostly gaming)